# How can I use setState in Flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate

Why when I use switch case or if condition inside setState I need to click twice to get the result in Text-Widget

here is the switch case with setState

```
  var name = 'Mustafa';
  int? index;

                onTap: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    switch (index) {
                      case 0:
                        {
                          name = "Mustafa";
                        }
                        break;
                      case 1:
                        {
                          name = "Kamel";
                        }
                        break;
                      case 2:
                        {
                          name = "Mohammed"
                              "";
                        }
                        break;
                      case 3:
                        {
                          name = "Hussain";
                        }
                    }
                  });
                },
```

and here is the Text widget

```
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
            Center(
                child: Text(
              name,
            )),
            Center(
                child: Text(
              name,
            )),
            Center(
                child: Text(
              name,
            )),
            Center(child: Text(name)),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

I tried everything I can think of but I couldn't solve it

Comment: use `switch case` outside of `setState`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to initialize the index variable with a value like zero instead of null value. Then, Add a default block to the switch statement and see if it works.

Comment: The problem is with the widget, because when I print it, it change in the run table directly but in the phone screen it need me to click twice